# What happened to Data::UUID in SLES?

Tags: perl, uuid, sles12

I have a Perl program with tradition (i.e. I use it over 10 years), but today I realized that it cannot find `Data::UUID` any more.
I also tried to install a corresponding package from the SLES software repository, but I could not find one.

AFAIR it still worked in January this year.

I'm using perl-5.18.2-12.23.1.x86_64 from SLES 12 SP5.
Could it be a packaging error?
It also seems that several "perldelta" manual pages (describing the changes between versions) are missing, so I cannot look up whether the standard distribution had changed.

I also see the same problem in openSUSE Leap 15.3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the module is not in one of the official repositories, but it's available through the build service:
[Data::UUID for SLE 12 SP4](https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries/devel:languages:perl/perl-Data-UUID/SLE_12_SP4),
[Data::UUID for SLE 15 SP3](https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries/devel:languages:perl/perl-Data-UUID/SLE_15_SP3),
[Data::UUID for Leap 15.3](https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries/devel:languages:perl/perl-Data-UUID/openSUSE_Leap_15.3)

However I'm not sure whether it actually existed in official repositories before; maybe I had installed the package for some other source, and the package got lost during some Perl upgrade.